# What can be done about files with CRC errors?

Tags: data-recovery

I have some files that are refusing to copy from one drive to another, giving Cyclical Redundency Check errors on windows 10.

I really don't think there's a problem with the drive(s) they're both pretty new and chkdsk and sfc do not report any errors.

I'm wondering what I can do to repair these files?

--UPDATE

The files in question were previously copied from another destination, so file recovery programs designed for recovering deleted data were of no use to me. In the end, I found a very useful tool called JFileRecovery (a JS applet available from softpedia site) - this allowed me to copy the files despite errors (and in some cases it healed them -- apparently).
I no longer use Windows Explorer to copy files, I use Teracopy instead which verifies the copied data, hopefully avoiding a similar situation in future.

Comment: DO we talk about specific files or all files in source media? WHat are the source, target media?

Comment: Just some specific files. Source is an external USB SSD drive, target is USB HDD. I have tried using windows explorer copy and Teracopy, both say CRC code 23. I suspect problem is with source files as I have tried copying them to other locations, like local C drive and that doesn't work either

Comment: Have you try to open these files with appropriate app?

Comment: Yes, I tried one of them - it was an audio file and it gives errors but still loads the audio (used adobe audition). On closer inspection there is some missing data.

Comment: In such case my assumption is the part of source media (and/or filesystem) is broken. You can try to recover the files with Recuva, Disk drill, PhotoRec. But to increase the probability of recovery do not initiate any write operation on this media.

Comment: Thanks - I have looked into file recovery - although most of them are designed to recover deleted data... in my case this data was already copied from elsewhere previously so there's nothing to recover. Have edited original post to show my compromise solution.